# how to add bandwidth limit in ubuntu grive?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I use grive to sync folder with Google drive in Ubuntu, but I want to set a bandwidth limit on grive sync.

I use this command for sync in 50 kbytes speed limit:

```
grive -p /home/purval -U 50 -D 50
```

but it's not working.even not showing any error message.My `grive` version is **grive version 0.5.1-dev**

Comment: When describing a problem, simply telling us "it's not working" is not helpful. How is it failing? Any error messages? Does the command not run? Does it run but crash? Does it run but do nothing? How are you checking the bandwith use? Please [edit] your question and tell us more about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default grive installation from [github](https://github.com/Grive/grive), upload & download speed parameters would not work even if you pass `-U 50 or -D 50` , grive will use max upload / download bandwidth of your system.

Grive is using `CURL` under its hood for file transmission and there is parameter in curl which can control bandwidth while transmission i.e `(curl_off_t)` [details here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE.html).

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Pass a curl_off_t as parameter with the maxspeed. If an upload exceeds
>   this speed (counted in bytes per second) the transfer will pause to
>   keep the speed less than or equal to the parameter value. Defaults to
>   unlimited speed.

There is file named **grive/libgrive/src/http/CurlAgent.cc** in source code which contains

> CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE with mMaxUpload

as option for upload, mMaxUpload is the value in kbps which set by using grive with  `-U 50`   and

> CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE with mMaxDownload

as option for download, mMaxDownload is the value in kbps which set by using grive with `-D 50`

**to control bandwidth just add `(curl_off_t)`** like

`static_cast<curl_off_t>( mMaxUpload )` instead of only `mMaxUpload` & `static_cast<curl_off_t>( mMaxDownload )` instead of only `mMaxDownload` in above file & save it.

After saving file, compile the source code & run it as described in repository & after successful compilation you can now set upload & download bandwidth by `-U 50 / -D 50` where 50 is kbps.